# Rounding floats after modf()

Tags: binary, floating-point

I am trying to make an effective `modf()` function that uses floats instead of doubles.  An embedded application I am working on only supports the float type.

My `modf()` function works as expected with the exception of float rounding errors.

Consider the float number 12345.67.  The current version of my `modf()` function simply subtracts the integer part from the input to get the fraction part.  What I expected was 12345.67 - 12345. = 0.67 , but it doesn't work right.

The original mantissa for 12345.67 is this:
100 0000 1110 01.10 1010 1110   <- 0x40E6AE decimal point = 13

Separated into integer and fraction components is this:
100 0000 1110 01.00 0000 0000   <-- Integer 0x40E600
000 0000 0000 00.10 1010 1110   <-- Fraction

My `modf()` function normalizes the fraction to:
010 1011 1000 0000 0000 0000   <-- 0x2B8000

Because of the influx of 13 zeros from the right, the number is not 0.67 as expected, but instead, something like 0.6600178.

I need to fix the rounding error so that it is closer to 0.67.  The binary version of 0.67 is this:
010 1011 1000 0101 0001 1111   <-- 0x2B851F
Notice that the last 3 nibbles have data now.  The first half is the same.

If I change the 12th bit from the right to a 1, I get something like 0.67002
010 1011 1000 1000 0000 0000   <-- 0x2B8800

This is good enough for my needs, but if I did that when the input float was actually 0.67 to start with, I would have the wrong value.

What is the proper way to apply bias to a float in this situation?

Comment: Several sources on the Internet say that if you cast the original float to a long, and then subtract that from the original float, you will get the correct fractional part.  Otherwise, have a look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20121030234640/http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/modf_8c-source.html

Comment: These numbers look very, very dubious to me. Especially the claim that changing a single bit would change a floating-point value by 0.01. One bit could be 1/64 or 1/128, but not 0.01. I'd advice you to check your numbers.

Comment: Yes, in its simplest form, the routine is essentially:

Comment: @Robert Harvey Hit return too quick. Yes, in its simplest form, the routine is essentially: <br>IntPart=(float)((unsigned) InFloat); <br>Frac=InFloat - IntPart;<br>This works for small integers, but there is extra code to handle large integers such as 1E20 for example.

Comment: @gnasher729  By toggling the third new zero to a 1 when more than half the mantissa is shifted away seems to be working. I've had a lot more problems with rounding because floats are so small.  Would still like to hear how others are handling rounding like this.

Comment: I get the sensible looking 0.669922 instead of something weird like 0.6600178 with [this very simple C program](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsIwEEX3@YpQERKwxbeLqsuCOz9AkDRpaqCdSJoKIn57TFtbu3AV5s6Ze8LDnHPnJgp4UYsM7ysrlI5uR4RkoZnF5fNaaiFJN50gaV6KXgjjPrJnZiw@4I6hhNRQqRwyQQc@HvDEMO7Z7wKH/X1DmMzWBlokRm@EFHg/U0AeWomxk/mGxXK13kTb3a869Wn/XdYq78ZXSBJM5QWCGf4bpnSknnuvcx8) without doing anything special. What platform, language, compiler etc. are you using?

Comment: Also note your function, as written in your comment, will not work properly for negative numbers.